# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: w has to be a number or a string at Connection

Tags: mongodb, express

Anyone has an idea why I am getting this error : " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: w has to be a number or a string at Connection." ? I got this error while I was running the code below. It's purpose is to check if a user is in a mongodb database if not it creates a new user by the user email and the hash password.

I don't know if there is any relation, the code seem to work well, but when I updated my mac to catalina OS yesterday I started having this issue.

```js
routerAuth.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema)
    if (result.error === null) {
        Profile.findOne({
            email: req.body.email
        }).then(profile => {
            if (profile) {
                const error = new Error(
                    'The email is already in use. Please choose another one'
                )
                res.status(409)
                next(error)
            } else {
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password.trim(), 12).then(hashedpassword => {
                    let newProfile = new Profile({
                        first: req.body.first,
                        last: req.body.last,
                        password: hashedpassword,
                        email: req.body.email
                    })

                    Profile.insertMany(newProfile).then(profile => {
                        res.json(profile)
                    })
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Try adding a .catch block to Profile.findOne promise.

Comment: Thank you for your help,I gave it a try but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Check whether the Promise is being resolved or rejected. If it is getting rejected, paste the detailed error log here.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested. this is the result I got   "error": {
        "operationTime": "6754414467615817729",
        "ok": 0,
        "errmsg": "w has to be a number or a string",
        "code": 9,
        "codeName": "FailedToParse",
        "$clusterTime": {
            "clusterTime": "6754414467615817729",
            "signature": {
                "hash": "38e2Mt0iCFbOolZqkqpz+o0LxPE=",
                "keyId": "6737882210780577793"
            }
        },
        "name": "MongoError"
    }

Comment: Is it still producing an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning? I need to know whether the problem is in the findOne operation or the insertMany operation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I was busy. I figure out what was going on. On the mongo.connect function I was missing the attribute "useUnifiedTopology: true" and I removed the w on DB_CONNECTION = mongodb+srv:/@s.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority, and it works

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure where this error comes from (I found a pull request from 2016, which allegedly fixed this issue), but when I changed the url parameter order, I didn't get this anymore.

So instead of this:

```
/<database>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

write this:

```
/<database>?w=majority&retryWrites=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I'm not sure why but on my case, when I removed the "&w=majority" portion from the MongoDB connection string it worked.