# No write concern mode named 'majority { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })' found in replica set configuration

Tags: mongodb, heroku, postman

Hello any help would be very much appreciated with this issue. I am using Heroku and MongoDB to host my database and application. as of now I am using Postman to query the data base. the problem I have been having is when I try to add say a new user to this data base via POST. I get this error.

**No write concern mode named 'majority { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })' found in replica set configuration**

I have been doing a lot of reading and found a few suggestions on how to fix this. I know it is to do with the heroku config var. problem is everything I find or try simply does not work.
I have tried everything on this page

['No write concern mode named 'majority`' found in replica set configuration' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65305856/no-write-concern-mode-named-majority-found-in-replica-set-configuration-err).

and this page

[UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: w has to be a number or a string at Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617287/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongoerror-w-has-to-be-a-number-or-a-string-a)

here is the config I am using

**mongoose.connect( mongodb+srv://user:password@my-db.vj9wk.mongodb.net/myapplication?retryWrites=true&w=majority { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });**

if I remove the &w=majority I get an timeout error. so far the only edit I can get to work that does not cause a time out issue is this.

**mongoose.connect( mongodb+srv://user:password1977@my-db.vj9wk.mongodb.net/myapplication?retryWrites=true&w= { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
found in replica set configuration**

but with that config I get this error

**Error: MongoWriteConcernError: No write concern mode named ' { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });'
found in replica set configuration**

I am using mongodb V5.0 I am starting to feel this could be the issue from what i have been reading and that I need to roll back to ver 4.4. only issue with doing so is I worry I will loose all of my data or break my data base.

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:password@my-db.vj9wk.mongodb.net/myapplication?retryWrites=true&w=majority, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }");
```

or

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:password@my-db.vj9wk.mongodb.net/myapplication?retryWrites=true&w=majority&useNewUrlParser=true&useUnifiedTopology=true");
```

However, I think `useNewUrlParser` and `useUnifiedTopology` are deprecated anyway, so you may simply skip them.

Comment: I can not think you enough !!

Comment: this config fixed the issue

Comment: mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:password@my-db.vj9wk.mongodb.net/myapplication?retryWrites=true&w=majority&useNewUrlParser=true&useUnifiedTopology=true");

Comment: In this case please accept the answer.